# I can't pass variable from text file to evaluate in casper.js how I could solve this

Tags: javascript, variables, asynchronous, casperjs, evaluate

I'm trying to enter a manually a value in a  website using evaluate of casper.js

but when I view  the results of variable is `undefined`

this is my code

```
 requestHeader = fs.read('userinput.txt');


casper.waitFor(function _check(){
    newData =fs.read('userinput.txt');
password=newData;
    return data !== newData;
});
casper.wait(1000); // additional wait to make sure that the file writing has finished
casper.evaluate(function(newData) {

   document.querySelector("input#ctl00_bodyContentPlace_txtUser.columnaCampo").value = "37392747"+newData;
  document.querySelector("input#ctl00_bodyContentPlace_txtpass.columnaCampo").setAttribute('value', newData);
}, newData);









casper.then(function (){
    console.log("esxx"+newData);
});
```

How I could solve

Please help me

Comment: You're not declaring newData. Try adding `let newData;` to the top of your file?

Comment: `evaluate` does not support closures.

Comment: and how I could pass variable in the website ?

Comment: – Graham P Heath I declare the variable but the code is not working